# Jfrog pipelines source sync is stuck in "Sync in progress" state

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I have added a pipeline source using my repository as per the steps mentioned in [the developer doc](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Pipeline+Example%3A+Hello+World).

But, the sync is stuck in processing since an hour, it only shows ***Sync in Progress..*** in the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things you can check here:

1. The token you have created has enough permissions on the repository which you are trying to add as a source. Make sure the token you have created has following permissions:

   | SCM | Permissions |
   | --- | --- |
   | Github | **repo** (all); **admin:repo_hook** (read, write); **admin:public_key** (read, write) |
   | Bitbucket | **Account**: Read; **Pull requests**: Read; **Workspace membership**: Read; **Projects**: Read; **Repositories**: Admin; **Webhooks**: Read and Write |
   | BitbucketServer | Admin permission for **repositories** |
   | Gitlab | token needs to granted these scopes at minimum: **api**, **write_repository** |
2. Even after ensuring the above it doesn't work, then do validate the yml using `yml validator` in UI and check if its a valid yml. Please refer [Pipelines Validating Yml](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+Pipeline+Sources#ManagingPipelineSources-ValidatingYAML)